# AWS Appsync deployment strategy

Tags: continuous-deployment, aws-appsync

We are launching an Appsync project to production soon, and my team are suggesting to introduce blue/green deployment to reduce possible downtime, with the ability to rollback to the original schema if an error occurs. From my limited knowledge in Appsync, there is no build-in deployment strategy like Lambda linear or canary deployment using codedeploy.

On top of our mind, we are thinking of creating a new AppSync and use route53 weighted routing to control the traffic. This solution involves implementing complex workflows to both monitor and rollback. Is there a better strategy for deployment?

We are using serverless lib for our deployment.

Comment: No response to this in 2 years? We have the same questions right now and wondering what approach you went for in the end?

Comment: I can see from articles like this one that you can use deployment strategies for the back end resolver deployments, but not for the AppSync layer itself - https://dlozitskiy.medium.com/safe-deployment-strategies-for-appsync-lambda-datasources-20db91d82651